# webgl textures using pixel data not rendered

Tags: webgl, textures

While drawing textures using pixel data in webgl, the texture is not rendered. the object displays in white color instead. Can somebody point me towards the error in the following code?

```
 function handleLoadedTexture(texture ) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 16,16,0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.data);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    try{
    }
    catch(e){       
            console.log("Error : "+ e.name + "\n"+ e.message);
            console.log(gl.getError());
    }
}


var neheTexture;
var data;
function initTexture() {
    neheTexture = gl.createTexture();

    data =[];
    for(var i=0;i<256*4;i++)
    {       
            if(i%4==0 || i%4==3)
                    data[i] = 1;
            else data[i] =0;
    }
    neheTexture.data =  new Uint8Array(data);

}
```

Comment: Show the code used to draw your object.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is almost certainly in your drawing code, so please post that as well, but there is one thing I'd like to point out:

You are initializing the texture with red and alpha channels set to 1, but I'm pretty sure that's not doing what you think it should. Texture data like this is described in bytes, which have value ranges of 0-255. That means that 1, instead of meaning "full intensity" like you probably thought, is actually 1/256 intensity (0.004 on a scale from 0 to 1). That means that your code is producing an almost entirely transparent and only slightly red tinted texture.

If you want fully opaque red you'll actually want to do your loop like so:

```
for(var i=0; i<256*4; i++) {       
        if(i%4==0 || i%4==3)
            data[i]=255;
        else 
            data[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. its resolved now.. i got confused because RGB values in shaders are from 0 to 1.